# Swap fragments and change data after swap

Tags: android-fragments

I have and "edit" activity and corresponding "edit" fragment (both extending standard Activity and Fragment respectively). From the edit fragment, I can call two other fragments, A or B, (via interface with the activity). Framents A and B simply extend standard Fragment as well.

Both the fragments, A or B, return a value (again via interface with the activity), and I want to use this value in the edit fragment.

However, back in the activity, if I have 'replaced' the edit fragment with one of either fragment A, or B, how do I then update the edit fragment and show it again, with the new/updated value from the A or B fragments (as the edit fragment's view is no longer in the edit activity's container, a simple FrameLayout)

i have tried combinations of Add/Hide fragments, but can't get that to work. Also, somehow using savedInstanceState doesn't appear to be an option. At the moment, it seems the easiest solution is simply to make fragments A and B as DialogFragments, and interface between them and the edit fragment. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I have figured out a solution that appears to work.

Comment: I have figured out a solution that appears to work.
1) Use fragment transaction and add either fragment A or B as applicable.
2) Use fragment transaction and add to back stack.
3) Use fragment transaction and hide the "edit fragment".
4) When fragment A or B "return" (via interface), find the applicable view in the frame layout, instantiate and set the component as required.
5) Set the fragment's (A or B) reference to null. Yes, does mean you keep a reference to all three fragments within the activity, but the references to framents A or B are null when the "edit fragment" is displaying

Comment: (continued)
6) Use fragment manager and pop the back stack.